# marketo smart list filters exclude matching records

Tags: marketo

Is there a way to use the smart list in a campaign to exclude records that match a filter?

I've got a custom table linked to the lead records, but it's a many-to-one style.  I'm trying to suppress lead records where the history records match certain values.

Problem is that there seems to be no way to do it.  I can have it include leads with no history records or leads with history records without certain values, but if the same lead has multiple history records, it will show up if either record has a value not in the exclusion.

What I want is the leads where NONE of the history records for it has those certain values, not simply to exclude the history records that match.

If this were a sql join statement, what I'm getting is:

```
select * from leads 
join history on history.leadid = leads.id and history.myval != 'x'
```

but what I want is:

```
select * from leads
where id not in (select id from history where myval = 'x')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do it by creating a couple of smart lists

a> A smart list that will checks for all the people who have that custom object AND have the exact value(s) that you want to Exclude

b> Then create another smart list with criteria like,
All the people who have,
1> That custom object
AND
2> Who are NOT in the first smart list A

That should give you the people you are looking for

Hope this helps

Rajesh Talele

Comment: Sounds good but how do I combine them into a final smart list?

Comment: That was the solution.  Sorry it took me a while to come back and mark it as the answer.